# How to use a concatenated string for get Method of requests?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to write a small crawler to crawl multiple wikipedia pages.
I want to make the crawl somewhat dynamic by concatenating the hyperlink for the exact wikipage from a file which contains a list of names.
For example, the first line of "deutsche_Schauspieler.txt" says "Alfred Abel" and the concatenated string would be "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred Abel". Using the txt file will result in heading being none, yet when I complete the link with a string inside the script, it works.

This is for python 2.x.
I already tried to switch from " to ', 
tried + instead of %s
tried to put the whole string into the txt file (so that first line reads "http://..." instead of "Alfred Abel"
tried to switch from "Alfred Abel" to "Alfred_Abel

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

file = open("test.txt","w")
f = open("deutsche_Schauspieler.txt","r")

content = f.readlines()

for line in content:    
    link = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s" % (str(line))
    response = requests.get(link)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    heading = soup.find(id='Vorlage_Personendaten')
    uls = heading.find_all('td')
    for item in uls:
        file.write(item.text.encode('utf-8') + "\n")

f.close()
file.close()
```

I expect to get the content of the table "Vorlage_Personendaten" which actually works if i change line 10 to

```
link = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred Abel"
# link = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Abel" also works
```

But I want it to work using the textfile

Comment: I can't replicate your problem.Its working fine.

Comment: Using the txt file, i get "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'" instead of the correct result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
Although there are no additionaly lines on the file, the content array displays like
['Alfred Abel\n'], but printing out the first index of the array will result in 'Alfred Abel'. It still gets interpreted like the string in the array, thus forming a false link.
So you want to move the last(!) character from the current line.
A solution could look like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

file = open("test.txt","w")
f = open("deutsche_Schauspieler.txt","r")

content = f.readlines()
print (content)
for line in content:    
    line=line[:-1] #Note how this removes \n which are technically two characters
    link = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s" % str(line)
    response = requests.get(link)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    try:
        heading = soup.find(id='Vorlage_Personendaten')
        uls = heading.find_all('td')
        for item in uls:
            file.write(item.text.encode('utf-8') + "\n")
    except:
        print ("That did not work")
        pass

f.close()
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem in your text file where you have used `"Alfred Abel"` that is why you are getting the following exceptions

> uls = heading.find_all('td')
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Please remove the string quotes `"Alfred Abel"` and use `Alfred Abel` inside the text file `deutsche_Schauspieler.txt` . it will work as expected.

Comment: No, the lines in the text file are without " "; the first line is literally
Alfred Abel

Comment: I have tested on my laptop with "" and Without "". With "" failing as you mentioned but Without "" is working as i said in my comment.

Comment: @Hereks :  Ok got the problem.Can you please check there are no empty new lines in your text file.It is giving problem because of that.So when looping through it after first search it is getting empty line and throwing the error.

Comment: I pressed backspace multiple times on the left side of Alfred Abel, so there should be no empty line before the first and pressing downward behind Alfred Abel wont move the cursor to the next line, so I assume there are no empty lines. (Saved the file after that and tried again with same results)

Comment: Strange!!! I have tested above two options what I mentioned and got error so thought to tell you.If everything is right it should work which working on my laptop.

Comment: Are you on Windows? I'm starting to think its a Linux problem

Comment: Yes I am on windows

Comment: Before use request just print the link and see what it is printing

Comment: terminal says: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred Abel
for print (link) in line 11